# how to change the text of the button that is in .kv using the button that is in .py in kivy?

Tags: python, button, text, kivy

I have 2 buttons, the first is created in a .py file and the second in a .kv file, how can I make it so that when you click on a button that is created in .py, the text of the button that is created in .kv changes! how can i change it?

```
class Start(MDFloatLayout):

    def test1(self):
        self.button.text = 'Hello'


    btn1.bind(on_release = lambda x: Start().test1())
```

but when you click on the button, the text of the button in .kv does not change; if you write print('Hello') there, then 'Hello' will be displayed, but the text of the button will not change! how can i change it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found to do this is to:

- create an id in the kv file for the button
- in the test1 function change the value of the id.text by calling self.buttonid.text = 'hello'

Let me know if you need more details, if you provide an example of your kv file I can show you how to edit it